# How to increase an extra field in an event of Joomla component JEvent

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am using JEvent with Joomla 2.5 and I need to increase an extra field while editing an event detail from admin section of Joomla.

I think there should be a proper sequence of steps to do it. If any have any idea of how we can do it, Please suggest me.

Thanks,
Pramod

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer of this question and detailed as below - -

1. First of all in the file \administrator\components\com_jevents\libraries\saveIcalEvent.php add your field name in the function 'save' as like below - -
   $data["RUNNING_DISTANCE"] = JArrayHelper::getValue($array, "running_distance", "");
2. Now in the file \components\com_jevents\libraries\iCalEventDetail.php add an extra class property to the class iCalEventDetail same as below - -
   var $running_distance = 0;
3. Add this in the file \components\com_jevents\libraries\iCalEventDetail.php in the function 'convertData' as below - -
   $this->processField("running_distance","");
4. And now finally add a an extra field "running_distance" in JEvents table jevents_vevdetail

This is what I did by myself. Your queries and suggestions are highly invited.

Thanks, 
Pramod